# Do I need a lab in order to test new ideas in designing quantum circuits

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, quantum-algorithms

I would like to know how to test new ideas certainly on a circuit level. Do I require a lab? if so where can I find one I live in Houston. Does nt quantum eliminate the necessity of a lab and can I use this fact to create a virtual lab? Much appreciated for the help

Comment: If you mean simulating quantum circuits (where lines represent qubits, little boxes represent unitary gates) on a computer then you don't need a lab - Google any of the following: IBM quantum composer, cirq, qiskit, pennylane, pyquil. If you mean designing circuits for quantum devices (e.g. superconducting qubits) then you definitely need a lab but can do some design with a multiphysics simulator (e.g. COMSOL)

Comment: Have a look at Qiskit Metal: https://qiskit.org/metal/